# Angular 7 - How to show error messages in child components of form when submitting the form

Tags: angular, forms, submit, formgroups

I'm implementing a signup page with **Angular 7** and **Angular Material**. In this page I use a password input component which gets a reference to the used FormGroup. The outer component handles the logical parts (f.e. how the FormGroup looks like, how the FormControls are defined and how each input is validated). When I click into the password input and click somewhere else/enter anything invalid, the error message of the input is shown correctly. But when I click on the submit-button **without touching any input fields**, the FormControl of the FormGroup are validated (the FormControl even says that it has an error) but not touched, so **no** error messages are shown.

I've already looked up how to solve this behaviour. Some suggested to manually set all form controls as touched after clicking on the submit-button. Yes, this works but I would like to have a general solution so I don't have to do this for every form I have in the future.

**signup.component.ts:**

```
export class SignupComponent implements OnInit {

    signupForm: FormGroup;

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.signupForm = new FormGroup({
            'password': new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
            'contact': new FormControl('', [Validators.required])
        });
    }

    onSubmit() {
        console.log('Form validity: ' + this.signupForm.valid);
    }

}
```

**signup.component.html:**

```
<mat-card class="signup-card">
    <h1 class="signup-title">Sign up</h1>

    <form [formGroup]="signupForm" #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" fxLayout="column">
        <!-- Password -->
        <app-base-password-input [parentForm]="signupForm"></app-base-password-input>

        <!-- Contact -->
        <div class="signup-contact">
            <mat-checkbox formControlName="contact" required>We may contact you.</mat-checkbox>
            <mat-error *ngIf="form.submitted && signupForm.controls['contact'].hasError('required')">Please check this box.</mat-error>
        </div>

    <button class="signup-button" mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit">Sign up</button>

    </form>
</mat-card>
```

**app-base-password-input.component.ts:**

```
export class BasePasswordInputComponent {

    @Input() parentForm: FormGroup;

    constructor() { }

}
```

**app-base-password-input.component.html:**

```
<mat-form-field [formGroup]="parentForm">
    <mat-label>Password</mat-label>
    <input matInput type="password" formControlName="password" required>
    <mat-error *ngIf="parentForm.controls['password'].hasError('required')">Password is required.</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

**What I expect:**
When I click on the submit-button without touching/clicking on any input fields, every input shows an error message (f.e. Hey, user! I'm required!).

**What actually happens:**
When I click on the submit-button without touching/clicking on any input fields, only the FormControls defined in the outer component show error messages (this case: contact checkbox). My input components show no error messages (this case: password component).

I hope I posted everything you needed to answer my question. If something is still unclear, I'll update the post :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I know to do it is, as you say, setting every FormControl as "touched" manually in the `onSubmit()` method.

**SignupComponent.ts**

```
onSubmit(){
    console.log('Form validity: ' + this.signupForm.valid);
    touchAllElements(this.signupForm);
}

touchAllElements(formGroup:FormGroup){
    Object.keys(formGroup["controls"]).forEach(element => {
        formGroup.get(element).markAsTouched();
    });
}
```

To avoid repeat this method in every component with a form, you could move `touchAllElements` to a service

Comment: I wish there was a way to do this automatically. But still thanks for the answer :)